# Will paprika taste good in my soup?

Tags: spices, soup

I've been making a soup that has an onion + garlic + carrot + celery + flour base, and then chunks of sweet potato and potato as well as barley added. I've been spicing it with salt, pepper, garlic powder, and basil. Now I want to substitute paprika for the basil. Would that ruin the soup?

Comment: The question in its original form would have been closed as a poll question - we do not accept question whose answer is a list of equally good ideas, see the [faq]. I know the edit changed the meaning, but else I would have had to close it completely.

Answer (score 2):

Paprika brings out the best in savory flavors. I'd go with something a little hotter to compliment the sweetness of the sweet potato - but not too hot, or you'll loose the regular spuds.

Comment: hmmm. how about hot paprika?

Comment: There is quite a bit of variation in paprika flavor/warmth. If you happen to get a dull batch of the stuff, a little pinch or two of Arbol chili powder fixes it up pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Go for a barbeque or curry: both of those will go well with the veggies you're using.  Actually, your best bet is to experiment and try lots of different spice combinations.  Soups are very versatile.